# Mongo throwing "Element name 'name' is not valid' exception

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm updating a simple field.

```
var filterDocument = new BsonDocument { { "name", "alice" } };

var newDocument = new BsonDocument { { "name", "Alice" } };

collection.UpdateOne(filterDocument, newDocument);
```

But when I reach the the update statement I get an exception `{"Element name 'name' is not valid'."}`

What's wrong with that element name?

**Update**

Re-writing it to this:

```
var filterDocument = new BsonDocument { { "x", "alice" } };

var newDocument = new BsonDocument { { "y", "Alice" } };

collection.UpdateOne(filterDocument, newDocument);
```

Throw the exception `{"Element name 'y' is not valid'."}`

Also, `UpdateOne()` or `UpdateMany()` makes no difference.

Also, from the shell it's fine.

```
> db.crud.update({name:'alice'},{name:'Alice'})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: Strange... Is the "invalid name" with `filterDocument`, or `newDocument`?

Comment: Good point!  Appears to be the `newDocument`.  I just changed it to `x` and got the same exception, but with `x` instead.

Comment: Hm.. I was gonna say, maybe its because it gets `"name"` mixed up with some term, but guess not... Try changing `filterDocument`'s name to `"y"`, then try changing its value to  `"Alice"`

Comment: I did change both, one to `x` and one to `y`

Comment: And same error? Try changing the value of `filterDocument` to be `"Alice"`, with a capital `"A"`. I'm trying to find all the possible differences that could cause the second document to create an error.

Comment: Just swapped `Alice` and `alice` over.  Still the exception on the filter document.

Comment: Okay, so at least we know its with `Alice`, but I don't see what's wrong with that...

Comment: I mean, I swapped them over, but the exception says as `Element name 'y' is not valid'.`  I've evem changed them to `foo` and `bar`, same result.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In contrast to `update`, `updateOne` seems to require an update operator;

```
> db.test.updateOne({name:'alice'},{name:'Alice'})
2016-02-16T19:04:07.689+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators

> db.test.updateOne({name:'alice'},{$set: {name:'Alice'}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

...which means your document should probably look like;

```
var newDocument = 
    new BsonDocument { { "$set", new BsonDocument {"name", "Alice" } } };
```

...or if you really mean to replace the entire document, use `replaceOne`, which should work with your existing documents to replace the entire matching document.

Comment: I wondered if it was something like that.  Replace v's edit.  I'll give it a go!